# Recover a "lost" type parameter

Tags: c#, generics

Basically, my question is: Is there some way to "recover" a type parameter that was lost by upcast to a non-generic base type, e.g., `Object`. Here is an example of what I mean:

Consider I have received an `Object` `l` from a library and I know that `l` is an `IList<T>`, but I do not know the `T` (but I do know that it is a reference type, no value type). However, the exact type of `T` is not important, because all I want to do is to pass `l` to a generic method:

```
void doSomethingWithList<T>(IList<T> l){ ... }
```

However, I cannot do that, since I do not know to which type to cast `l`, i.e., I would like to do the following:

```
doSomethingWithList((IList<>)l);
```

I want to tell the compiler that `l` is an `IList` and it should call the method and bind the unknown type parameter to its parameter `T`. But it doesn't work like this. Do I have any options? Can I somehow pass an object for which I "lost" the type parameter to a generic method?

Comment: Can't you use co(ntra)variance and just pass an `IList<object>`?

Comment: @Davio, `IList<T>` is not contravariant.

Comment: Generic parameters are resolved at compile time, so it seems unlikely that you could do something at run-time to make it work.  On the other hand, could you just use an `IList` parameter instead?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using reflection:

```
var interfaceType = l.GetType().GetInterface("System.Collections.Generic.IList`1");
var itemType = interfaceType.GetGenericArguments()[0]; // This is your T
var method = this.GetType().GetMethod("doSomethingWithList").MakeGenericMethod(itemType);
method.Invoke(this, new object[] { l });
```

But if you can, it's probably better to change `doSomethingWithList` to accept a non-generic list...

Comment: Is there a clean way to use `typeof(IList<>)` instead of `"System.Collections.Generic.IList`1"`?

Comment: @TimS., you can use `typeof(IList<>).FullName`

Answer (score 2):

If you know it's safe, the simplest solution is to use `dynamic`:

```
doSomethingWithList((dynamic)l);
```

Otherwise you could check that `l` implements `IList<T>` for some `T` and call the method through reflection:

```
var listType = l.GetType().GetInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IList<>));
if (listType != null)
{
    Type elementType = listType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    var method = this.GetType().GetMethod("doSomethingWithList").MakeGenericMethod(elementType);
    method.Invoke(this, new object[] { l });
}
```

Comment: `dynamic` seems to be interesting and a lot faster than reflection (and a lot less to write). Will it work as expected in this case?

Comment: @gexicide - Yes it should work in this case although I wouldn't expect it to be faster than reflection since it will end up doing pretty much the same thing internally.

Comment: As long as there aren't other overloads of `doSomethingWithList`, and your type only implements one `T` in `IList<T>`, this is a place where `dynamic` will be quite straightforward: it'll work as expected. I'd expect it to be around as fast as reflection, maybe faster after it's cached things the first time.